Visual studio debugger will not step into source code of separate project (same solution) (c++)
I have a visual studio solution with two projects, one that compiles to a .exe which depends on a project that compliles to a dll. When I try to step into a function in the dll, it skips over it.
I tried setting a breakpoint in the function, and it gave a warning saying "The breakpoint will not be hit, no symbols have been loaded for this document." Then it links me to this article. It says to check if the modules and symbols have been loaded, and both the exe and dll are loaded as well as their symbols. I then tried to resolve all 3 of the possible causes they listed, yet the debugger will still not step into the dll code. I also read from some other answers that I should disable debugging "Just my code" in the debugger options, and I've also tried copying the .pdb file of my dll into the output directory of my exe project, and neither of these worked.
Any ideas on what might be going on?

Was the DLL built without debug information, a stripped-down and optimized "Release" build?

@user4581301 Are you talking about building with stripped .pdb files? If thats what youre talking about, then no the /PDBSTRIPPED linker option is not enabled.

No, I was thinking more setting the build type to Release rather then Debug. After the code's been through the optimizer's blender breakpoints often make no sense whether you have symbol information or not.

Is your program actually loading the DLL you think it's loading? Check the path to your DLL in the loaded modules list. Make sure that's the DLL you built. Check the build log to ensure your DLL output target is where you think it is. One way to verify is to delete the DLL, run your program and make sure it fails, then rebuild the DLL. Try setting breakpoints elsewhere in your DLL code -- it may be that some stuff has been optimized completely away. It's not uncommon to find that a breakpoint on some lines in a Release build is not possible.

Open the "Modules" window in VS and make sure symbols are loaded for that DLL. If they are not, from that window, you can load it from there.

@paddy its loading the symbols of the copy of my dll. I have two bin directories, one for the dll and one for the exe, but the program wont run unless i copy the dll to the same directory of my exe.

@user4581301 i tried building it in release and it still skipped the breakpoint

@RetiredNinja yes

@RetiredNinja i already tried this, as i said in my post, and it did not work.
